# Getting the records count at current page in rails with will_paginate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to get the number of records at current page. I am using will_paginate gem for pagination. When trying to get the collection.count I am getting total number of records?

```
@collection = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).all
```

when I try to get the count of collection it returns the total entries. How to get the records count of a current table

Comment: As the paginated collection will *most likely* be looped on to display each element, this means the paginated collection will become an Array. This means you can do `@collection.size` to get the size of the Array containing the paginated collection (without doing useless computation because the pagination collection is / will be an array anyway)

Comment: That returns the size of the array. ie per_page value

Comment: I think I misunderstood your statement then: *I need to get the number of records at current page*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u need total entries in entire query:

```
@collection.total_entries
```

If u need entry count in current page:

```
@collection.size
```

Meanwhile u dont need to call last `.all` scope in pagination. Just try:

```
@collection = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

Comment: We can also use @collection.length to get the entry of current page

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@collection.total_entries
```

Comment: I tried that too return the total number of records

Comment: and? what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to find the number of records for the current page. But @surveys.size is not returning the number of records in the current page, instead, it's returning the number of records if the current page had been filled. [image: Rails 5.2.2 ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]]

```
@collection.length
```

is the one that provides the needed result.

Comment: please add clarification also

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current number of items on current page the you should do `@collection.size`. 
If you want the total number of items the you should do `@collection.count`

You can try setting the `page` to last page to see the difference.

Also use

```
@collection = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

as the paginate will return only the corresponding set, configured with `page` and `per_page` params.

Answer (score 0):

```
@collection.entries
```

is giving you the entries on the current page. If you for example paginate 25 entries, it will show the 25 entries in an `Array` class

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 7 returns the total number of items disregarding pagination:

```
@collection.total_count
```